# Not able to connect to MySQL and PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, connection, localhost, local

I tried to use Jupiter notebook to connect MySQL and PostgreSQL. I don't know why it did not work anymore. The error message is "ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module".
Below is the traceback from this internal error.
In the beginning, I have no problem using sqlite3 to link database
Here is my code using squlite3

```
pitchfork_db = sqlite3.connect("pitchfork.db") 

reviews.to_sql('reviews', pitchfork_db, index=False, if_exists='replace')
artists.to_sql('artists', pitchfork_db, index=False, if_exists='replace')
content.to_sql('content', pitchfork_db, index=False, if_exists='replace')
genres.to_sql('genres', pitchfork_db, index=False, if_exists='replace')
labels.to_sql('labels', pitchfork_db, index=False, if_exists='replace')
years.to_sql('years', pitchfork_db, index=False, if_exists='replace')

I can perform the query I want to

pitchfork_cursor = pitchfork_db.cursor()
pitchfork_cursor.execute("SELECT title, artist, score FROM reviews WHERE 
score=10")
colnames = [x[0] for x in pitchfork_cursor.description]
pitchfork_df = pitchfork_cursor.fetchall()
pd.DataFrame(pitchfork_df, columns=colnames)
```

I got error message using MySQL:
"Traceback (most recent call last):
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Here is my code to MySQL:

```
    import mysql.connector

    mysqlpassword = os.getenv("mysqlpassword")

    dbserver = mysql.connector.connect(
    user='root', 
    passwd=mysqlpassword, 
    host="localhost"
    )
```

I got error message using PostgreSQL:
"Traceback (most recent call last):
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting"

Here is my code to PostgreSQL

```
    import psycopg2

    pgpassword = os.getenv("pgpassword")

    dbserver = psycopg2.connect(
    user='postgres', 
    password=pgpassword, 
    host="localhost"
    ) 
    dbserver.autocommit = True
```

I stuck here for several hours, any comments will be great! Thank you!

Comment: Are you using `inspect` somewhere else in your code? Also not seeing the traceback.

Comment: both connector should try to use sockets, which failed.